# Codeigniter form validation to check whether a value of input has changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

I'm using `codeigniter 3.0.4` and now stuck on a basic problem. I have an `<input type='text'>` with a default value generated using Jquery.

My Question, how do I check whether the value has been changed or not when I submit a form?

If the value now is different from default given value, it'll do a callback validation (it's actually to check email availability). Otherwise if the value is still the same as the default given value it will skip the callback validation.

---

This is my modal

```
<div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody">
   <form id="contactform" role="form" method="POST" action='<?php echo  base_url('administrator/kategori/editcategory');?>' >
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="kategori"> Nama Kategori </label>
           <input type="hidden" name="id" class='id' id='id'>
           <input type="text" class="form-control edit-category" name='edit-category' id="edit-category" required autofocus>
       </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success confirm-edit"> Edit Data </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

as you can see, that form above submits the data to `administrator/kategori/editkategori`

and this is my `editkategori()` function

```
public function editcategory(){
 if($this->input->post()){
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('kategori', 'Kategori Baru', 'required|callback_correctcategory');

     if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->data['result']   = $this->admincrud->getcategorylist();
        $this->data['categoryname'] = $this->admincrud->fetchcategoryname();
        $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);  

     } else {

        $tobesent = array(
           "id" => $this->input->post('id'),
           "kb" => $this->input->post('kategori')
        );

        $result = $this->admincrud->editcategory($tobesent);
        if($result){
          $this->session->set_flashdata('result', 'Kategori Sukses Diubah');
          redirect('administrator/kategori');
        }

     }

 } else {

    redirect('administrator/kategori');

 }

}
```

This is the `JQuery` function to automatically give values to corresponding text when the modal above is shown

```
$('.toggle-edit-modal').click(function(){

  var id           = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var categoryname = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();

  $('.id').val(id);
  $('.edit-categoryname').val(categoryname);

})
```

in the set of validation rules, I put the callback `correctcategory()`, and this is the `correctcategory()` function :

```
public function correctcategory($str){

    $sterilizedkey  = strtoupper(trim(str_replace(" ", "", $str)));
    $tobeshown      = ucfirst(strtolower($sterilizedkey));
    $this->CI->db->select("upper(trim(REPLACE(`CategoryName`, ' ',''))) as `CategoryName`");
    $this->CI->db->from('category');
    $result = $this->CI->db->get()->result_array();
    $data   = array();
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $data[] = $value['CategoryName'];
    }
    if(in_array($sterilizedkey, $data)){
        $this->set_message('correctcategory', 'The faculty has been registered before');
        return false; 
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

With the code above, the system will evaluate every value submitted through the form.

The problem comes when I open the modal, and a textbox with default given value appears. How can I skip the `correctcategory` validation if I directly submit the form but without changing the value of the textbox, or when the new value and the old given one are exactly the same ?

Comment: what have you done so far? can you show some code?

Comment: updated with code. please check my code back

Comment: in your PHP you are validating an input with name of `kategori` but I do not see that input in your HTML.

Comment: you say this _"...or when the new value and the old given one..."_ but what do you mean by old value? I dont see that you are presetting your HTML inputs at all. Meaning those inputs will never have an "old value" they will just be blank

Answer (score 0):

you have to store the original value in a hidden text box. and check it with the text box which has values.

for eg:

```
<input type="text" id="orig" value="your email">
<input type="hidden" id="hid" value="your email">
```

then in jquery on submit check like the following

```
var original = $('#orig').val();
var static = $('#hid').val();
if(original == static){
  alert("not changed");
}else{
  alert("changed");
}
```

Note: this code is only for example as you did'nt shared any of your code

Answer (score 0):

If the value being set by Jquery is known by you, then the controller should as well be aware( guess this is the category database value)
Based on the assumption that default value is known.
To solve this, the controller function needs to be aware of the default value you are setting for the input.

```
class Categories extends CI_Controller {

public function edit()
{


   // form submited?
   If ( $this->input->post()) 
   {
       $this->load->model('category_model');

       $error = null;
       $success = false ;

        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        // now you were looking for 'kategori' instead of 'edit-category'
        $posted_cat_name = $this->input->post('edit-category'); 
        // get the db record
        $category = $this->category_model->fetch( array('id' => $id ));

        if( !$category->id)
        {
           $error = 'Category not exist' ;
           // set flash and redirect
            redirect('categories/admin_list');
        }
       // category remain the same
       If( $posted_cat_name ==  $category->name)
       {
          $error = "No changes made" ;
       }
       else if( $this->category_model->update($id , $posted_cat_name) == false)
       {
          $error = 'Error occured updating category' ;
          // get the error and log_message() for debuging
       }
       else
       {
          $success = true ;
          // set flash data and redirect

        }


  }
  // do you need this remaining code? aren't you suppose to redirect back to admin list where the form was posted  ?
   $this->data['result']   = $this->admincrud->getcategorylist();
   $this->data['categoryname'] = $this->admincrud->fetchcategoryname();
  $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);  
  }
 }
```